# JQuery Datepicker values does not get submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i try to submit some basic data to a PHP script via GET.
Two of my 5 values are populated by a JqueryUI datepicker.
When I check those two input-fields via alert, they show up correctly, however they don't get passed to the PHP script on submit.

**Code:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geb0qef5/1/)

*index.php* - Note: the `addHourOptions()` php functions just add some select `<option>`-fields, nothing fancy.

```
<?php
include('inc/functions.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>Filter</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <!--<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ajax/ajax.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
            <form id="filter" action="filter.php" method="GET">
                <label for="date-from">
                    from Date: <input id="date-from" type="text" />
                </label>
                &nbsp;
                <label for="date-to">
                    to Date: <input id="date-to" type="text" />
                </label>
                &nbsp;
                <label for="time-from">from Time:
                    <select id="time-from"  name="time-from" size="1">
<?php addHourOptions(); ?>
                    </select>
                </label>
                &nbsp;
                <label for="time-to">to Time:
                    <select id="time-to" name="time-to" size="1">
<?php addHourOptions(); ?>
                    </select>
                </label>
                &nbsp;
                <label for="corps">Corporation:
                    <select id="corps" name="corps" size="1">
                        <option value="98256608">Scroll Lock.</option>
                        <option value="955058602">German Angels</option>
                        <option value="98323502">Rat der 66er</option>
                        <option value="98183461">Girl Friends Please Ignore</option>
                        <option value="98371266">Know your Role</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                &nbsp;
                <button type="submit" id="filterButton">Filter</button>
                <button type="button" id="debug">Debug</button>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*main.js*

```
//initialize datepicker: yy-mm-dd / yesterday
$(function(){
    $.datepicker.setDefaults(
            $.extend($.datepicker.regional[''])
            );
    $('#date-from').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}).datepicker("setDate", -1);
    $('#date-to').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}).datepicker("setDate", "TODAY");
});

// set defaults for time timespan-dropdowns
$(function() {
    $('#time-from option[value="19:00"]').attr("selected",true);
    $('#time-to option[value="23:59"]').attr("selected",true);
});

$('#debug').click( function() {
        alert($('#date-from').val() + " " + $('#date-to').val());
}
```

*filter.php* - only displays _GET variables for now, no logic

```
<?php
foreach($_GET as $key => $param){
    echo $key . " => " . $param . "<br />";
}
?>
```

So there should be 5 lines in the output of *filter.php*,
one for each form-value. But there are only 3.

Example Output:

```
time-from => 19:00
time-to => 23:59
corps => 98256608
```

Can someone please tell me why the two input-fields that contain
my dates just don't get submitted with the rest of the form?

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT:** I used the search here, and read many questions and answers about it, but nothing seemed to work for me.

Comment: If these input fields are set to "display: none" somewhere in css they will not get submitted.

Comment: @AlekosDordas they are not, but good to know, I sure did not know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<label for="date-from">
     from Date: <input id="date-from" type="text" name="date-form" />
</label>
&nbsp;
<label for="date-to">
     to Date: <input id="date-to" type="text" name="date-to" />
</label>
```

Create name attribute for them and I think your problem is solved.

Comment: Jep, now I feel stupid ... Thank you very much, I have no clue how I could miss that. Working fine now.

Comment: It is ok, no need to feel stupid. It can happen to anyone.